# How to populate SQL Server Compact/SDF tables from a text file in an ASP.NET WebPages site?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, asp.net-webpages, webmatrix-2

I've created a database in my asp.net web site (using WebMatrix).

The table contents will be static - the user will never change them or add records.

The table contents live right now in a text file, which I want to loop through to populate the site's table.

Is the normal way of populating such a table to add the insertion code to _AppStart, run it once, and then comment it out or remove it?

Comment: Why not add it during Development and deploy a populated database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either use [SqlCeToolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) in Visual Studio or write some code and run it from WebMatrix. I don't see the point in putting the code in AppStart. I would just create a separate file and right click on it and choose Launch In Browser.

Comment: I'm having problems with SQL CE Toolbox, but as it's a completely different question, I'll post a new one about that. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330310/why-is-sql-ce-toolbox-failing-to-parse-my-csv-file